# I try make productCode unique one eg p01 p02 etc.. by mongodb but don't work and don't best way

Tags: mongodb, mern

I try make productCode unique one eg p01 p02 etc.. by mongodb but don't work and don't best way

i thank best way auto in db like id but how

// get total number of products in db and add 1 to it and add p in front of it

```
const productCount = await Product.countDocuments((count)=>count);              
const newProduct = new Product({
    productCount: 'p'+productCount+1,
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description 
});
```

Comment: There seem to be two questions here.  The first is about how to have the database enforce uniqueness. In that regard you'll want to create a [unique index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/). Your secondary question is around how to have the application generate unique values. The proposed approach may cause performance or concurrency issues, but there should be other questions that give suggestions for alternative ways to do this.

Comment: yes I want to generate unique values p01 p02 p03 p04 etc... so may you give more details about that

Comment: Would relying on the automatically generated (and unique) _id field satisfy your needs?

Comment: yes but some job failed interview because  Product code (should be a unique one eg: P01, P02, etc...